# JQuery function (Window Resize)

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I'm using this JQuery function to equal my div heights:

```
//equalize funciton
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
```

With this OnLoad:

```
$(window).load(function(){
equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border"));
});
```

It requires that I refresh the page in order for it to take affect (after the page is resized). I would like it to either do it as the user is dragging the window, or just refresh the page after.

Which is recommended? I know the page resize won't be very smooth if the JQuery function is consistently reloading. Also, how could I change my code to fit either option?

Answer (score 1):

Call your function on both [`$(window).resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). It will be OK.

**EDITION:**
I think this is what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).resize(function() { 
    equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm i'm running all three now, but it no longer resizes the divs at all.
'
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(){
 $("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border");
 });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).resize(function() {
   $("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border");
 });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border");
 });
    </script>

Comment: `$("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border");` is not correct.
call this one `equalHeight(group)` with an appropriate argument.

Comment: That equals the heights, but the page still needs a refresh, like previously.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can adapt this function, going to look and see what others have created to solve this issue.